# log4j in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, log4j

How to configure log4j in NetBeans?

Where we need to put log4j.properties file? I tried putting it inside WEB-INF, inside src folder, inside my main application, but always it is throwing FileNotFoundException.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the folder src/main/resources/

Comment: Thnx for reply, but still the same exception